# How to use String.Replace

Tags: c#, string, replace

Quick question:

I have this String `m_Author, m_Editor` But I have some weird ID stuff within the string so if I do a `WriteLine` it will look like:

> '16;#Luca Hostettler'

I know I can do the following:

```
    string author = m_Author.Replace("16;#", "");
    string editor = m_Editor.Replace("16;#", "");
```

And after that I will just have the name,
But I think in future I will have other people and other ID's.

So the question: Can I tell the `String.Replace("#AndEverythingBeforeThat", "")`
So i could also have

> '14;#Luca Hostettler'
>
> '15;#Hans Meier'

And would get the Output: Luca Hostettler, Hans Meier, without changing the code manually to `m_Editor.Replace("14;#", ""), m_Editor.Replace("15;#", "")`...?

Comment: Will there always be 1 and only 1 `'#'`?

Comment: No, cause it will raise to 20++ if you have more users ;) but the # will always be there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want a regex of "at least one digit, then semi-colon and hash", with an anchor for "only at the start of the string":

```
string author = Regex.Replace(m_Author, @"^\d+;#", "");
```

Or to make it more reusable:

```
private static readonly Regex IdentifierMatcher = new Regex(@"^\d+;#");
...
string author = IdentifierMatcher.Replace(m_Author, "");
string editor = IdentifierMatcher.Repalce(m_Editor, "");
```

Note that there may be different appropriate solutions if:

- The ID can be non-numeric
- There may be other ignorable parts and you only want the value after the last hash

Comment: Maybe anchored to the beginning of the string?

Comment: @JoeWhite: Yup, was just fixing that as well as adding another example :)

Comment: Hi @Jon, yes you're right, this is exactly the method I searched for, already tested and it worked right away :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use regex or (what i'd prefer) `IndexOf` + `Substring`:

```
int indexOfHash = m_Author.IndexOf("#");
if(indexOfHash >= 0)
{
    string author = m_Author.Substring(indexOfHash + 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this would also replace the start of "Don'tReplaceThis#foo". I guess it depends on whether there's *always* an ID.

Comment: @JonSkeet: in my understanding OP wants only the part after the hash.

Comment: It's always there^^ so why you'd prefer that if you even have more code @TimSchmelter?

Comment: Well we know that's the case *if it's an ID before the hash*, but we don't know whether sometimes there may not be an ID at the start of the string, but there's still a hash somewhere. It's entirely *possible* that this would work, of course. It can also be simplified to just `string author = m_Author.Substring(m_Author.IndexOf('#') + 1);` as that will still give the whole string if there's no hash. (And I believe it's optimized appropriately.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: imho it's not simpler since it doesn't allow to handle the case that there is no hash(f.e. log, throw exception, output or skip).

Comment: @Unlockedluca: because it is more readable and more efficient. But as Jon has mentioned you can use a one-liner if it's always there: `m_Author.Substring(m_Author.IndexOf('#') + 1)`. I just wanted to show the proper use  of the return value of `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

or just,

```
var author = m_Author.Split('#').Last();
```

Comment: This assumes there's no other hash in the string. What about `#14;#Stuff#Other stuff`?

Comment: I am assuming that only the portion after the **last** `'#'` is required.

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that I don't see anything in the question to justify that assumption. Of course it *may* be valid. It's hard to tell. Although in this case I'd use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` probably.

Comment: The question is ambiguous and I agree a Regex is more valid for the general case and possibly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can Split you string with # using     string.Split() function this will give you two strings first everything before # and second everything after #

Answer (score 0):

use String.Format

```
    int number=5;
    string userId = String.Format("{0};#",number)
    string author = m_Author.Replace(userId, "");
```

Comment: That assumes you know what the number is - and in that case, it would be easier to just use concatenation: `m_Author.Replace(number + ";#", "")`

Comment: oh,yes,then use regex)as other answers says)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is filter out everything that is not a letter or space, try:

```
var originalName = "#123;Firstname Lastname";
var filteredName = new string(originalName
                                 .Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || 
                                             Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                                 .ToArray());
```

The example will produce `Firstname Lastname`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<char> originalName = "15;#Hans Meier".ToList();
string newString = string.Concat(originalName.Where(x => originalName.IndexOf(x) > originalName.IndexOf('#')).ToList());
```